# SQL server Log shipping Copying failed due to incorrect username and password

Tags: sql-server, windows, log-shipping, event

I have 2 sql server 2008 servers with log shipping. Now im trying to add one more secondary server to the existing log shipping. While copying the log files to secondary I got the below error on SQL server.

*Copying log backup files. Primary Server: 'MASTER', Primary Database: 'Test', Backup Source Directory: '\X.X.X.X\ls\', Backup Destination Directory: 'C:\LS'*
 **Error: The user name or password is incorrect.*

Meanwhile on primary Server I found the below error on event viewer.
**An account failed to log on**.
Network Information:

```
Workstation Name:   Secondary
Source Network Address: 172.X.X.X
Source Port:        49174
```

> This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on
>   the computer where access was attempted.
>
> The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which
>   requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the
>   Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or
>   Services.exe.

Can anyone guide me to resolve this?

Comment: Have you validated that the account executing the log copy job has permissions to write to the share on the destination machine? It's generally best to use a unc path for the destination.

Comment: All the three instances are in workgroup only and same subnet, and share folder has full rights to everyone.

Comment: Check that the account you are using has a similar account on the desitnation service with the same password. If the password is different on that machine it could cause this.

Comment: Great, it worked, SQL agent running under the user Administrator on all 3 servers, I just reset all the passwords as same.

can you please tell me why it didn't work with different passwords or sql agent ran different user?

Comment: Because you are in a workgroup environment it is going to use the executing credentials to authenticate against the remote machine. If the remote machine password does not match then it will fail the auth. Having the same password allows the creds to be passed along accurately and authenticaiton to succeed.